# Want to sync gsutil from certain date

Tags: amazon-s3, rsync, gsutil

Here's my predicament. I want to sync my S3 bucket with one on the google cloud. Simple use of gsutil and done, except we have a few terra's of data and for rsync to run through it all takes quite a bit of time. Is there an argument for gsutil that will allow too sync from a specified date? I have looked around for a bit at this, a point into the right direction would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no `gsutil rsync` argument that does date comparison.  You could accomplish this with `gsutil rsync` by including the date as part of your object naming scheme.

Note that for syncing from S3 to Google Cloud Storage, the [Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/) is recommended and could save you from running the transfer through your own local machine.

Comment: Ahhh, I was hoping I was wrong in that thought. Thank you for clarifying that.